# How to use a hyperlink to link open another file?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I've created a hyperlink to open another page, but it doesn't open the file. I'm using the code below. Can you give me suggestions to link/open the other file page?

This is my code:

```
<a href='www.google.com'>Back <a/>
```

This is my current URL website

```
http://192.168.1.100/asisto_new/app/colorlib_regform_12/index.php
```

My problem is when I've clicked the "back" hyperlink, it link to this URL website:http://192.168.1.100/asisto_new/app/colorlib_regform_12/www.google.com.

How should can be direct link to www.google.com website without this url http://192.168.1.100/asisto_new/app/colorlib_regform_12/index.php

Other question is if I want link to other html page, how I write in the code? For example, I want open home.php. How to insert it become http://192.168.1.100/asisto_new/home.php

Comment: You need to include the protocol when creating an absolute URL: `<a href="https://www.google.com">Back<a/>`

Comment: Yup. You are right. Do you know if I want link to other html page, how to link it?

Comment: Assuming you want to link to a local page use a relative URL. If you want to understand the difference between a relative and absolute URL, try this: https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is you need to use protocol
and your second mistake is in your tag. the tag is not `<a/>` it will be `</a>`

your code must look like this : `<a href='https://www.google.com'>Back <a/>`

And your second answer is look like this code .It will open new html page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://192.168.1.100/asisto_new/home.php">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Protocal is missing in your href attribute use the below

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Back<a/>
```